# Can't figure out why isset is not working

Tags: php

I have a button that I need to call a function on when it is clicked but for some reason, the `isset` function is not seeing the button as being clicked.

Below are the two lines in the php/html file:

```
 <input type="submit" id='details' name='details' class="pull-right btn-sm btn-primary" value='Show Details'/>


 <h4><?php echo $subject_details; ?></h4>
```

The below is in an external.  I know it is included because if I add an `else` to the `if` statement, and set that variable to something different, it will change.

```
 $subject_details = '';

 if(isset($_POST['details'])){

    $subject_details = 'button clicked';
    setDetails(); 

}
```

Thanks to anyone looking at this!

Comment: should that be a submit button or merely a button?

Comment: From what I have read, it must be a submit button.  Now you make me wonder if the button must be in a form.

Comment: ah - but of course you need to access post so you must be submitting a form..

Comment: Even though I put it in a form, it still isn't working.  It's jut reloading the page.  So what I am doing is not submitting a form.  I have several button that will each direct to another page but depending on which button is clicked is what will be shown on the next page.

Comment: Using a form and submitting will always reload the page. I would suggest that you use ajax - you don't need a form and you can send via post or get whichever you wish. The variables will be available to you after and the page does not need to reload

Comment: Do you have an example of this?  All I need to do is know when/which button is clicked so I can redirect to another page and then load the page with the proper data.  I just don't understand why `isset` isn't working because I have accomplished similar tasks like this in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isset() function only works for input type submit. What you can do is embed the button in a form and let the page reload to itself to grab the variable stored in an external php. As an example:

```
//in your main.php

<?php 
include 'external.php';
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<h4><?php echo $subject_details; ?></h4>


//in your external.php

<?php
$subject_details = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $subject_details = 'button clicked';
}
?>
```

Comment: So this does work , (I didn't realize the button had to be in a form) but is there a better way?  I will have five buttons and depending on which one is clicked, the next page will have different information. Seems like there would be a better way.

Comment: you can add five different buttons inside the form with different names and in your external php just declare five different isset() functions.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full code example, I can't be sure, but it's possible you're not specifying the `method="post"` attribute on the `<form>` tag. A form defaults to `method="get"` therefore you would need to use `isset($_GET['details'])` instead.

A working example would be:

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <input type="submit" name='details' value='Show Details'>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['details'])) {
    echo $_POST['details'];
} else {
    echo 'No post data submitted';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could play around with this... might help

```
<!-- head section -->
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
        var oCol=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');
        for( var b in oCol ) if( b && oCol[b] && oCol[b].nodeType==1 ) oCol[ b ].onclick=function(e){
            alert( this.tagName + ' '+this.id+' was clicked...' );
        }.bind( oCol[b]);
    };
</script>




        <input type='button' id='b1' value='Button 1' />
        <input type='button' id='b2' value='Button 2' />
        <input type='button' id='b3' value='Button 3' />
        <input type='button' id='b4' value='Button 4' />
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps since this is JavaScript and I am working with PHP. The function that needs to be called is querying a database.  I'm not looking for an alternate soluction.  I need helping understanding why something that I have used in the past is not working.

Comment: potentially this is an ID 10T error. You seem to be getting confused - php will never know if a button has been clicked as it is a server side language and javascript, for the most part, is client side. Of the two, javascript will know when a button is clicked and can do the necessary redirection - in whatever manner you see fit. If the button submits a form - the page will reload - at which point post vars will be available if the form was submitted using post.